# Running both Windows 8 and Windows XP on the same computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, multi-boot

I need to run Windows 8 and occasionally Windows XP in my laptop. So, is it possible to use two operating systems like Windows 8 and Windows XP?

It should ask me while staring the computer for example which OS you need to load then I may choose XP, or 8 as I wish.

Any idea?

Comment: install windows XP first, and then WIndows 8.

Comment: but i have installed windows 8 already so is there any problem if i install windows xp now?

Comment: I am sure this is probably a duplicate, but there are so many dual boot questions on the site I can't even find it.

Comment: @patty general rule when you want to install two different versions of the same software on a machine at the same time - Always install the older one first. The new software may be able to recognise the old version, and work out how to co-exist (eg set up dual-boot, know which files can be overwritten with newer versions safely, etc), but there's almost no chance the old software will recognize and know what to do with the newer version if the new one's already on there.

Comment: Is there XP mode in Window 8 like there is in Win 7?

Comment: An easy solution would be to install [**VirtualBox**](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and then create a Windows XP machine.  That way you can even run Windows 8 and Windows XP at the same time.  It works great and is easy to do.

Comment: You can, in fact, install XP Mode on Windows 8. http://lifehacker.com/5965889/how-to-run-windows-xp-for-free-in-windows-8

Comment: From my experience with XP Mode, it doesn't run as well as it does in VirtualBox.

Comment: having probs with VM! `:(` @http://superuser.com/questions/540071/cant-use-any-devices-in-usb-port-in-virtualbox