# cant use any devices in USB port in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed VirtualBox under windows 8 operating system to use Windows XP. Everything seems great but i can't use any devices through USB port in virtualbox. I have enabled the VirtualBox Extension Pack 4.2.4, but nothing happens. I am using the latest version, downloaded today! So, why any USB ports are not working in windows XP under VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the USB Controller first. You can find it under Settings > USB.

Also, make sure you install the Guest Additions too, they are required for USB to work, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: thanks for the help, i will try n let u know if there is any prob :)

Comment: @MaxPat. you're welcome :)